# Huge drag response time in cordova application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, drag-and-drop

I'm using drug and drop UI for my cordova android app. I've noticed that response time is such big that it can't be used for games for example. I've tested it on samsung galaxy tab 3 which is fast enough for drag and drop purpuses:)

I'm using jquery mobile library to drag `<img>` element:

```
jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js

$('#img').draggable();
```

Is it possible to improve response time? maybe using another library?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing (you haven't described clearly enough to be sure) then HTML5 native drag and drop may suffice http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: @Xotic750, I'm just testing drug and drop response time. No heavy javascript code behind

Comment: Well I doubt you will get anything more responsive than a first class citizen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xotic750 was saing native functions works fast.

Also I've found [this tutorial](http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/javascript-touch-event-or-mouse-event-detect-and-handle-according-to-device/) very usefull